# Creating a transparent circle in overlay, around a view in superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-graphics, drawrect

I have a `UILabel` added as a subview in a `UIViewController`.
I am adding subview (overlay view) view on `UIViewController`.view.
How to make a transparent circle in overlay view so that the `UILabel` is visible from transparent circle.

**What I am able to do for now:**
I am able to create a transparent circle with **hardcoded coordinates**.What I want is that I just pass `UILabel` and get a overlay with transparent circle around `UILabel`.

Any thoughts.

My source code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Zh7km8csGiRzBpUVk2dFJ1WU0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try to create a `UILabel` with insets and apply border to it.

Comment: Are you want to create overlay view for Introduction of Application ?